# Row break of QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am working on a QGIS plugin and using a QPlainTextEdit (QGIS 2.18 -> QT4 / python 2.7) in python and try to list multiple files.
I add the files using the following lines:

```
def select_files(self):
        path = r"c:\temp"
        filt = "Text file(*.txt)"
        filenames = os.linesep.join(QFileDialog.getOpenFileNamesAndFilter(self.dlg, 
                                    "Select text file ",path, filt)[0]) 
        if len(filenames[0])>0:
            self.dlg.txteFilenames.setPlainText(filenames)
```

i.e. joining the list of files to a string with line breaks for each file.
This works fine (as it seems) and the self.dlg.txteFilenames is populated with the selected filenames, one for each row.

But then when I later try to use these files, one by one, I cannot parse it back to a list of files

```
filenames = self.dlg.txteFilenames.toPlainText().split(os.linesep)
```

This does not however split into a list of filenames but remains as one string.
I have tried to look for how QPlainTextEdit handles row breaks but I cannot find out how.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I think a QListWidget would serve your purpose better. It will allow you to select a given item, or get the entire list of items.